# What steps are needed to implement memcached in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, django-cache

I have my existing Django web application that uses a MySQLDB without memcaching.
I would like to implement memcaching to improve the responsiveness of this site. I see the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

However, these instructions leave me with some unanswered question(s). Is this all I need to do to get memcache working after I setup the memcached server? Or do I need to alter any of my code outside of settings.py? Does Django nicely handle all the memcaching operations behind the scenes for me whenever models are read or written? (If so, that's very cool!) How can I see what improvement the memcaching is having on the number of DB accesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done is just a set up of a Cache Backend.

In order to benefit from caching you need to find the places where it is appropriate and would have a positive impact on performance: your [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache), [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)..you can cache the whole views, templates, template fragments etc.

If you want some automation to help you, take a look at [Johnny Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/) package:

> Johnny Cache is a caching framework for django applications. It works
>   with the django caching abstraction, but was developed specifically
>   with the use of memcached in mind. Its main feature is a patch on
>   Django’s ORM that automatically caches all reads in a consistent
>   manner.

Or [`django-cache-machine`](https://cache-machine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package:

> Cache Machine provides automatic caching and invalidation for Django
>   models through the ORM.

There is also an interesting project called [`django-cacheops`](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) that is aiming to improve Django ORM caching, but it uses `Redis` backend.

Also, [`django_debug_toolbar`s caching panel](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/panels.html#cache) can help you in the future.

Note that django querysets have a built-in internal cache, but it has nothing to do with a cache framework.

Further reading:

- [Using Django querysets effectively](http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/06/08/django-querysets/)
- [Caching and QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

Comment: I have also added the following to my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES: 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware', 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'. The docs seem to suggest this will "cache my entire site". What does that mean? Isn't that what I'm after?

Comment: @SaqibAli this is about request/response. If the request headers allow to get the response from cache and if there was a request for the same URL with the same query parameters - django would retrieve the response from cache. Just read the whole chapter from the link you've provided. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SaqibAli did the answer help?

Comment: yes. It was helpful. But now my question has become more detailed/complex.. I posted a new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071619/how-to-use-memcache-with-django-when-retrieving-updating-model-instances-with